# Editing SMB-accessed Excel files with Mac

Tags: macos, smb

I'm having issues with Mac users being unable to edit and save an Excel file located on a server outside the network (SMB connection). Windows users accessing the same file initially see an Excel banner saying 'This file originated from an internet location and may be unsafe..', but can edit/save after clicking 'Enable Editing'.  No such option seems to exist for Mac users.  Grateful for assistance.

Comment: What are the error messages given by Excel?

Comment: How remiss of me! Excel just says the file is read only and tries to get you to save with a new filename..

Comment: And can you save a new file in the remote location?

Comment: No problem doing that. Just checking the offending file's permissions via 'get info' it gives 'You have custom access', but no further info.

Comment: Should add that saving after `sudo open <filename>` also fails.

Comment: Is the remote location a NTFS drive? Maybe it is a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Excel spreadsheet is opened, an "invisible" temp file is also created. Its file name usually begins with a tilde and/or a dollar sign, such as `~$foo.xlsx`. When you are finished working on the spreadsheet, this temp file is supposed to be deleted, freeing the file for other users.

Yet there are many circumstances where this file does not get deleted, or it lingers beyond its expected lifespan. Your users may have permissions problems, or the server's file system (under load) lags in executing its commands. Or maybe the user simply opens the sheet and walks away for a long lunch break and the server disconnects the user for inactivity. There are a lot of variables to account for.

If simultaneous editing of a single spreadsheet is your goal, I think your best bet at this time is to try Google's implementation at Google Drive -- true multiuser editing.

Comment: Better late than never

Answer (score 1):

We think this may have arisen because a file-use conflict between 2 users has generated a lock file that now prevents Macs from saving.  Still unclear exactly how to resolve, but I don't want to leave a question open if it doesn't have a general solution, so I'll leave it open for now and close off with this answer if nothing is forthcoming in the next few days.

Comment: Never considered it but Excel (well, all Office) do lock their files at a constant basis. Maybe a solution is to save the files, versioning them (however that would be quite confusing).